# How to assign type to API response when calling API

Tags: reactjs, typescript, response, fetch-api

I am using TypeScript in my project and when I use fetch to call the API, the type of response is any.

```
const response = await fetch(url);
```

I know the data structure of this response is an object

```
{id: string; code: string}
```

Can I use below way to assign the type to response? If not, may I please know the best practise for this requirement?

```
const response: {id: string; code: string} = await fetch(url);
```

If I only need id, is it ok to do so?

```
   const { id }: {id: string} = await fetch(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create typed fetch and use it where you need typed response:

```
async function typedFetch<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data as T;
}

// Consumer
const response = await typedFetch<YourCustomType>('some/api/1'); // Here response will be of `YourCustomType` type
```